# I'd like to capture several cell values from a CSV file and write to a new column

Tags: python, database, pandas, csv

So, I'm new to Python. I've been trying to apply the things I've learnt to real world problems. The task I've set myself is this..

I want to capture the two cell values '01/01/2018 and '08/01/2018' and print them into a new csv.file under the header value dates. I also want to create a new column which shows the value associated with that date in the original csv file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated or a point in the right direction.

### Original table

```
Hierarchy   | Dept   | Emp | Alpha | Bravo | Charlie | 01/01/2018 | 08/01/2018|
Hierarchy 1 | Dept 1 | JC  | h     | o     | l       | 0          | 2         |
```

### New table

```
Hierarchy   |Dept   | Emp | Alpha | Bravo | Charlie    | Date       |Value |
Hierarchy 1 |Dept 1 | JC  | h     | o     | l          | 01/01/2018 | 0    |
Hierarchy 1 |Dept 1 | JC  | h     | o     | l          | 08/01/2018 | 2    |
```

Comment: I would look into pandas, specifically the melt function.

Comment: @ChristianSloper Thank you! I'll look into that!

Comment: Let me know if you are stuck, I can write up an example if you want to.

Comment: @ChristianSloper If you could write up a demo that would be fantastic?

Answer (score 0):

As @ChristianSloper mentions in his comment, `pd.melt` is designed for this. In your case, here is a one-liner:

```
df
     Hierarchy    Dept Emp Alpha Bravo Charlie  01/01/2018  08/01/2018
0  Hierarchy_1  Dept_1  JC     h     o       l           0           2

pd.melt(df, 
        id_vars=df.columns[:-2], 
        value_vars=df.columns[-2:],
        var_name='Date', 
        value_name='Value')
     Hierarchy    Dept Emp Alpha Bravo Charlie        Date  Value
0  Hierarchy_1  Dept_1  JC     h     o       l  01/01/2018      0
1  Hierarchy_1  Dept_1  JC     h     o       l  08/01/2018      2
```

Comment: Instead of having the data frame within my code, could I create a variable which holds my csv file and I call that within pd.melt? 

I would also need to write the new data to a new csv file?

Comment: Yes, you first need to read in your csv with `df = pd.read_csv(path_to_filename)`. And you can store the result of `pd.melt` with `df2 = pd.melt(...)`.

Comment: ...And finally, you can write the `melt`ed DataFrame to a new csv with `df2.to_csv(path_to_file)`

Comment: Hey Peter,

I'm still struggling to implement your solution. Could you have a look at my git repo and look at the code, there is an outputted csv file in there, but it's formatted the data incorrectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!https://github.com/tdle/python

Comment: Ah, I think the issue is that in `data_export.py`, you are calling `pd.melt` twice and assigning the result to `df2`, overwriting the first results! Delete line 14, `df2 = pd.melt(df)`, and try re-running the code. Also, be careful about spaces within the quoted strings in your `id_vars`. `'Emp '` is not the same as `'Emp'`. I'm guessing the correct column name is `'Emp'`, without the space.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I am just going to go ahead and assume that your table is stored in a csv file.  So we will start by reading that in:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mytable.csv',sep='|')
pd.melt(df, 
       id_vars = ['Hierarchy   ', ' Dept   ', ' Emp ', ' Alpha ', ' Bravo ', ' Charlie '],
       value_vars=[' 01/01/2018 ',' 08/01/2018' ],
       var_name='Date', 
       value_name='Value')
```

Gives the desired result.

Comment: Hey Chris, 
Yes, my table is stored in a csv file, I'll give this a go! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey Chris, 

I gave your solution a try, but it came back with an error saying that the values in `id_vars` weren't in `columns`. 

Would you be able to check out my git repo and offer any advice on the code I've wrote so far? Cheers!  https://github.com/tdle/python

Comment: Sounds like the column names in the file are different than you had in your example. remember spaces are important.  after loading the dataframe print out "df.columns" to see the column names.

Answer (score 0):

After the help of the contributors I have completed my task, below is the code I've used! 
Thanks to the community for offering help!

```
"""
Transforms Data into Desired Format
"""

#import pandas module
import pandas as pd

#create variable where df = to data.csv
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

#create new variable for df.columns
cols = df.columns
#use .melt() function to complete data manipulation
transformed_df = pd.melt(df,
                         id_vars=cols[:6],
                         value_vars=cols[6:])

#Assert Data has been formatted correctly
print(transformed_df)

#create new csv file with new data
transformed_df.to_csv('melted_data.csv')

print("\nData has been Melted!")
```